# Accessing the path of a .CSV file from res/raw/ in Android using CsvJdbc

Tags: android, csv, file-io

I'm trying to access a file that I put into the res/raw folder in my Android project. I am using this .CSV file to use with the [CsvJdbc](http://csvjdbc.sourceforge.net/#features) jar which allows me to query it as if it where a database. I have seen many examples of grabbing it with an InputStream, for example...

```
 InputStream raw;
 raw = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.vehicles);
```

But I need to grab the file by creating a connection. i.e.

```
 Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:relique:csv:PathToFolderWhereCsvFileIsGoesHere");
```

Here is the full code.

```
    String[] holder = null;
    try
    {
      // load the driver into memory
      Class.forName("org.relique.jdbc.csv.CsvDriver");


      // create a connection. The first command line parameter is assumed to
      //  be the directory in which the .csv files are held
      Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:relique:csv:PathToFolderWhereCsvFileIsGoesHere");


      // create a Statement object to execute the query with
      Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();


      // Select the ID and NAME columns from sample.csv
      ResultSet results = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT model FROM vehicles where id = 200");


      // dump out the results
      for(int i=0; i < results.getFetchSize(); i++){
          holder[i] = results.getString("model");
      }


      // clean up
      results.close();
      stmt.close();
      conn.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to write a class implementing the CsvJdbc org.relique.io.TableReader interface that returns a java.io.Reader for each of your tables.  CsvJdbc then reads from this Reader object instead of from a file.

There is an example of this on the CsvJdbc web page http://csvjdbc.sourceforge.net